# Permission to debug host.exp.Exponent was denied

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, instruments, background-fetch

Thanks for your replys. I was a problem at instruments. I need to trigger background fetch on my iphone device. But when i click to record button, i get this error. How cna i resolve this issue, thank you.

[image]

I reinstalled command line tools with this command. I tried it with different devices.